# Which environment variable controls the location of .local directory?

Tags: 20.04, environment-variables, bashrc

Due to storage space constraints in my home directory, I need to move as much out of there as possible. I have moved caches and configs out by setting the `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` directories.

However, I cannot find the proper environment variable to set in order to move my `.local` directory somewhere new.

Is there a variable for this?

Comment: Explain please. A / with /home with no snaps and no private content does not exceed 10Gb. Besides personal content the biggest disk space waste is snaps. Dump those for the apt version 1st before messing with your system.

Comment: Perhaps ask a question about the problem you want to solve instead of about what *you* think is the solution to your problem. The famous XY question.

Comment: What programs are you using that continue to use `.local` after `XDG_*` is set to point elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is one. The [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) explicitly mentions `$HOME/.local/` several times which suggests that its hard coded.

I don't see why you need a variable though. Just move your `.local` to some other place and then symlink to it:

```
mv .local /wherever
ln -s /wherever .local
```

You can do this for any directory, allowing you to place them wherever you want. You could even move your entire home directory and replace that with a symlink.

Comment: "You can do this for any directory" if on the same disk ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind no, why? As long as the symlink doesn't need to be accessed very early, before the disk has been mounted, cross-filesystem symlinks are fine. I actually often do this since I have `/home` as a separate partition so if I move `~/.local`, it will be to another disk.

Comment: It might be worth noting that while symbolic links are an easy one-time procedure, but some applications might not follow them especially if to another filesystem (*e.g. APT for example will consider those as unsafe and will not follow them in some cases*) ... In which case a bind mount is the better alternative IMO.

Comment: @Raffa why would `apt` need to use directories under `~/`?

Comment: That is just an example that I came accross so mentioned it, but other apps might act similarly since APT developers aren't inventing its security policy I guess :-)

Comment: No, and `find` also needs `-L` to follow symlinks, but as a general rule, nothing important will rely on files in `~/.local` (or `~/` in general) so I don't think that will ever be an issue. I know it's never been one for me, anyway.

Comment: @terdon you will get really funky boots if / is on an ssd and .local is on a 5400 rpm disk :)

Comment: @Rinzwind why? I've had that in the past with `/` on an SSD and `/home` on an HDD (granted, probably 7200RPM). Why would that cause a problem? I can see how it would slow ay I/O bound operations, but apart from that?